# I can generate random numbers, but not identify min and max correctly in my set of numbers

Tags: java

So below is a script that will generate a list of `n` amount of random numbers between 1-100. I need to get it to where I can also identify the `max` and `min` of the random numbers generated in the command prompt after it runs the script. I keep running into the problem where it will just duplicate the number 2 additional times. Example when `n= 2: 12 12 12 43 43 43 22 22 22`

I think my problem is that when I use `int min = Math.min(b,b);` the for loop wants to repeat that part too. But if I put it outside of the script then I no longer have the variable b to use.

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
int b = (int)(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1;
System.out.println(b);
}
```

Comment: Your example code doesn't show how you are attempting to detect the max or min of the numbers. Please show the code you have tried and describe what is going wrong.

Answer (score 1):

if you insist on using Math library, you should consider the first number as min and max.

```
int n = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
int max = 0;
int min = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
   int b = (int)(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1;
   if(i == 0){
      min = b;
      max = b;
   }else{
      min = Math.min(min,b);
      max = Math.max(max,b);
   }
   System.out.println(b);
 }
 System.out.println(String.format("Min:%d , Max:%d",min,max));
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, however, this runs into a similar problem.  After compiling and running with the number "3" it says 19 min:19, Max:19 24, min: 19, max: 24 40 min:19, Max: 40

Comment: Thank you for the help! Ignore the above comment, this worked. Why is it that the variable b works in a different set of braces here without having to be identified again?

Comment: you're welcome, the variable b is not defined in different braces, its defined and used in "for" scope only

Answer (score 0):

- The `Random` class can generate **streams of random numbers** (with
  lower/upper bound).
- `IntSteam` can be collected into `IntSummaryStatistics`, which provide **min/max/avg/sum/count** information on the streamed data.
- When streaming, you can output (or process) the items over an **identity function**.

Combining all these results in a simple and elegant solution:

```
int n=Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
IntSummaryStatistics statistics = new Random()
    .ints(1, 100)
    .limit(n)
    .map(i -> {
        System.out.println(i);
        return i;
    }).summaryStatistics();

System.out.println("min: " + statistics.getMin());
System.out.println("max: " + statistics.getMax());
```

Answer (score -1):

first the word script in your question means the programming language ( javascript) ? 
or you mean the word script   ( probably in java we call it a class or program  not a script   the word script is mainly used in python  ) 
look easy fast way is to push the elements generated into an array and sort it

```
    Vector x=new Vector();
    for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
    {
        x.add(i,(Math.random() * (100 - 1)) + 1);
        //System.out.println(x.elementAt(i));


    }
    Collections.sort(x);
    System.out.println(x.elementAt(0));
    System.out.println(x.elementAt(x.size()-1));
```